# Process the result multiple times using Java Stream

Tags: java, for-loop, java-8, java-stream

How do I convert to Java Stream the `for-loop` part in the following codes?

```
    Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap() {{
        put("header", "Hello, world!");
        put("font", "Courier New");
        put("fontSize", "14px");
        put("color", "#0000ff");
        put("content", "hello, world" +
                "");
    }};
    Path templatePath = Paths.get("C:/workspace/spring-boot-demos/something.tpl");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(templatePath).stream()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(line -> {
                    String parsedLine = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < attributes.size(); i++) {
                        if (parsedLine.equals("")) parsedLine = this.parse(attributes, line);
                        else parsedLine = this.parse(attributes, parsedLine);
                    }

                    return parsedLine;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

```
public String parse(Map<String, String> attributes, String line) {
        return attributes.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(attributeMap -> line.indexOf("{{" + attributeMap.getKey() + "}}") != -1)
                .map(attributeMap -> {
                    String attributeKey = attributeMap.getKey();
                    String attributeValue = attributeMap.getValue();
                    String newLine = line.replace("{{" + attributeKey + "}}", attributeValue);
                    return newLine;
                })
                .findFirst().orElse(line);
    }
```

I find it difficult to implement it in `Java 8 Stream` way so that I'm forced to do it old `for-loop` construct. The reason behind this is that for every line of string, there might one or more placeholder (using `{{}}` delimiter). I have the list (`attributes`, `HashMap`) of the value to replace them. I want to make sure that before the loop of `Stream` leave every line, all of the placeholders must replaced with the value from the `Map`. Without doing this, only the first placeholder is being replaced.

Thank you.

Update:
This is the content of `something.tpl` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>HTML Generator</title>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: "{{font}}";
                font-size: {{fontSize}};
                color: {{color}};
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>{{header}}</header> {{content}}
        <main>{{content}}</main>
        <h1>{{header}}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the function of the for-loop to begin with? You're not doing anything with your index variable, and passing the whole map on each iteration

Comment: **Warning**: you are using a raw type: `HashMap`.

Comment: **Warning**: You are using *double brace initialization*. [That may lead to serious problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27521360/507738).

Comment: @MCEmperor Thank you. I used it for this post only but not for prod code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to replace every token in the given List ?

Here's how I would do it with streams :

1. Iterate over lines
2. parse each line only once
3. the parsing iterates over attributes, and replaces the current attribute

The `String[] pLine` may be was you were missing...

```java
package so20190412;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Snippet {

    public Snippet() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String> () {{
            put("john", "doe");
            put("bruce", "wayne");
        }};
        List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("My name is {{john}}, not {{bruce}}.", "Hello, {{john}}!", "How are you doing?");

        new Snippet().replaceAll(attributes, lines).forEach(System.out::println);

    }

    public List<String> replaceAll(Map<String, String> attributes, List<String> lines) {
        return lines.stream().map(l -> parse(attributes, l)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public String parse(Map<String, String> attributes, String line) {
        String[] pLine = {line};
        attributes.entrySet().stream()
                .forEach(attr -> {
                    String attributeKey = attr.getKey();
                    String attributeValue = attr.getValue();
                    String newLine = pLine[0].replace("{{" + attributeKey + "}}", attributeValue);
                    pLine[0] = newLine;
                });
        return pLine[0];
    }
}
```

Don't hesitate to ask if you don't understand some part.

HTH!

Comment: Thank you so much. Making `line` into `array` is the key.